# Code Metrics in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, notifications, build-automation, code-metrics

I was wondering what options were available with regards to code metrics in Visual Studio 2010.  I know there are manual metrics that can be run on your code from within the IDE, but are there any other options?

What I'm trying to do is this: My team and I are running Team Foundation Server 2010 and we have automated builds set up as well as notifications/alerts for those builds.  The notifications work well, but they give only basic information.  The notifications link to a page that give more detail on the build which is great too.  However, I'd still like to have metrics on my code with these builds and their notifications run automatically.

I honestly don't know if this is possible, but if it is, I was wondering if anyone knew exactly *how* to get it done.

If this can't be done, though, I was looking for any information on third-party tools (paid or free) that could accomplish my goals listed above.

Comment: TFS!=VS change the title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx). It has full integration with Visual Studio.

> NDepend is 100% integrated in Visual
>   Studio™ 2010, 2008 and 2005. If you
>   prefer you can use the standalone
>   VisualNDepend UI that collaborates
>   with Visual Studio™.

Comment: Thanks for this direction, although I have another question more specifically about ndepend now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587360/ndepend-integration-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 3):

Metrics tool is available from the command line now:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2011/01/28/code-metrics-from-the-command-line.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ccm tool from http://www.blunck.se/ccm.html
This tool is very fast and responsive.