# nDepend integration in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, notifications, code-metrics, ndepend

This stems from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585573/code-metrics-in-visual-studio-2010) I asked regarding code metrics.

I have been trying out nDepend as a tool to use in running metrics on our team's code.  I have to say that so far I am very impressed with the design, information given, etc.

My question now is if I can somehow combine the integrated nDepend tools with the builds and notifications for said builds in Team Foundation Server 2010.

Whether this be by automatically triggering the nDepend code metrics to run on a TFS build, or running the metrics and then either putting them in the email notification or at least linking them to the email.  I don't know if this is even possible, but if it is I was wondering if anyone could give me some direction in this area?  Or if not please let me know that as well/any other alternative solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will explain everything you need:

Integrate NDepend with TFS
http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_TFS.aspx

Comment: It'll take some tweaking and some more research on my part just for the fact that I don't know XAML very well, but I believe this is indeed exactly what I need!  Thanks for your help!